# How to unwrap a Future[Either[Throwable,T ]] to Either[Throwable,T]

Tags: scala

I have a `function`(`myFunc`) in `scala` that gives `Future[Either[Throwable,T ]]` . Now I need to unwrap and get `Either[Throwable,T ]` out of it and pass to as an input parameter to another function (`anotherFunc`).

```
def myFunc(input: String): Future[Either[Throwable, HttpResponse]] = {
  ....
}

def anotherFunc(response: Either[Throwable, T]) # signature

anotherFunc(myFunc("some string"))
```

Normally we use `map` to transform a `Future` but thats not helping me here

```
myFunc("some string").map { _ =>
            anotherFunc(_)
          }
```

This causes problem with the `return` of the block from where I am calling .

Comment: Why is `map` not helping here? Also, note that `map` doesn't unwrap anything because you can't safely unwrap a `Future` _(you would have to block a thread and wait for that)_; all `map` does is let you transform the `Future`

Comment: Just use a different name other than `_` or rather just do `map(anotherFunc)` or `map(anotherFunc(_))` or `map(it => anotherFunc(it))`

Answer (score 2):

You can't unwrap the value of a `Future` because a `Future` represents the result of an asynchronous computation that *may or may not be available* yet. By default, futures and non-blocking, encouraging the use of callbacks instead of typical blocking operations.

What you can do is either:

- use combinators such as `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` to compose futures in a non-blocking way.
- register a callback using the `onComplete` method, or `foreach` if you want to call a callback only when the `Future` completes successfully.
- block the main thread using `Await.result`,  if this is absolutely necessary, although is discouraged. If you want to transform the `Future` result or combine it with others, you should opt for the 2 previos non-blocking ways mentioned.

That being said. These are the preferred approaches:

```
  def anotherFunc[T](response: Future[Either[Throwable, T]]) = {
    response.onComplete {
      case Failure(exception) => // process exception
      case Success(value)     => // process value
    }
  }

  def anotherFunc2[T](response: Future[Either[Throwable, T]]) = {
    response.map {
      case Left(exception) => // process exception
      case Right(value)    => // process value
    }
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
  anotherFunc(myFunc("some string"))
  anotherFunc2(myFunc("some string"))
```

**EDIT**:
If you can't change the signature of `anotherFunc[T](response: Either[Throwable, T])` then just do:

```
  myFunc("some string").map(anotherFunc)
```

Comment: Actually changing the `anotherFunc` signature is not in my scope . Thanks for sharing this .

Comment: @Dibshare you could do e.g. `myFunc("...").map(anotherFunc)` to pass the Either to anotherFunc, but have the overall computation stay in a Future without having to block on it.

Comment: If you can't change the signature then what I would do is exactly as Dylan mentioned. I updated my answer.